# When does PowerShell filter results when using a Property flag?

Tags: powershell

## Question

When I use the command `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Volume -Property DriveLetter`, does PowerShell filter the results in the exection of the cmdlet? Does it return everything first and then select the requested and other essential properties? Does it provide a special query that returns only the requested data? How would I be able to discover this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it gives the detailed information for the volumes; Basically you should select the property after piping it.
But for this case it is always to use query and then piping it which will give a much detailed information.

```
Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from win32_volume" | Select DriveLetter
```

or

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Volume -Property DriveLetter | Select DriveLetter
```

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Volume | where __GENUS -eq 1 | select __GENUS, __CLASS
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example,

```
Get-WmiObject -Class 'Win32_Volume' -Property 'DriveLetter'
```

the command doesn't filter anything.  There is a `-Filter` argument for `Get-WmiObject` that [uses `WQL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392902(v=vs.85).aspx) to filter the results when it's retrieving the objects.  It performs the query:

```
SELECT * FROM $CLASS WHERE $FILTERTEXT
```